# ROS MoveIt PR2 Demo Launch Fails

Tags: moveit, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

An interesting one this as I'm not sure whether anyone else will be effected by this but here goes.

From a fresh install of ROS hydro and MoveIt hydro and installation of the 'ros-hydro-moveit-full-pr2' package I have been trying to run the simple moveit demo.launch file

i.e 'roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch'

However it unfortunately fails to load / work giving the error.

```
[ INFO] [1377888324.708150830]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1377888324.710933161]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1377888324.711348039]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1377888324.712989217]: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/odom_combined '
[ INFO] [1377888324.720032859]: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-5] process has died [pid 11657, exit code -4, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group __name:=move_group __log:=/home/michael/.ros/log/4ed43f30-11a4-11e3-b291-08863b2589c1/move_group-5.log].
log file: /home/michael/.ros/log/4ed43f30-11a4-11e3-b291-08863b2589c1/move_group-5*.log
[ERROR] [1377888327.017819527]: Object recognition action: Unable to connect to action server within allotted time
[rviz_Rinnegan_11584_115703587-6] process has died [pid 11685, exit code -4, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz -d /opt/ros/hydro/share/pr2_moveit_config/launch/moveit.rviz __name:=rviz_Rinnegan_11584_115703587 __log:=/home/michael/.ros/log/4ed43f30-11a4-11e3-b291-08863b2589c1/rviz_Rinnegan_11584_115703587-6.log].
log file: /home/michael/.ros/log/4ed43f30-11a4-11e3-b291-08863b2589c1/rviz_Rinnegan_11584_115703587-6*.log
```

Now I have never had this error before and it has also cropped up when trying to load up another moveit package for fanuc.

Certainly this is new to me, though I do seem to have an poor run in with action servers

```
 [ERROR] [1377888327.017819527]: Object recognition action: Unable to connect to action server within allotted time
```

It is possible to go the long way around through loading up rviz separately, along with a robot_description and then adding motion planning / robot_state within Rviz, however without running move_group I get no planning library loaded and running move_group.launch separately also fails.

What I find odd is that two weeks ago everything ran fine, on two separate computers, I go on holiday, take my slow netbook and install similar two the others the same ROS hydro / moveit etc and it runs fine. In fact I can load the damn thing up and run demo.launch with no problems right now, but coming back the other two computers seem to no longer like me, even after a purge and reinstall of ROS.

Has anything changed in the last two weeks with regards to MoveIt or move_group?

I'm kind of worried on whether I should touch my slow netbook at all in case it gets the same disease :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75769/ros-moveit-pr2-demo-launch-fails/) by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2013-08-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-09-01**:
Good question! In case you don't get any answers here, you should probably post to the [moveit google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/moveit-users), perhaps also with a link to this question. Most of the moveit support seems to be happening over there.

**Comment by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on 2013-09-02**:
I've managed to somehwat get around this problem but probably not in the correct way. I git cloned moveit_core and moveit_ros and catkin_maked them in my src, for some reason this partially failed and didn't complete moveit_ros_move_group, so I copied over the move_group node from opt/ros/... into the devel/lib/moveit_ros_move_group and it all seemed to work fine :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a recent change in Rviz (https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/680), which forced some plugins to be updated - including MoveIt's MotionPlanning plugin.

The fix is there, but currently only available via sources (hydro-devel) version. I expect there will be another release soonish.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on 2013-09-24**:
Well this is somewhat frustrating :).

I decided in some infinite glory to start over again as the Hydro deb has finally been released and reinstall everything. Of course this drove me straight back to the problem above again, however this time my somewhat work around no longer works :).

Anyway, first off some clarification, I have been under the assumption that all you really need to do is catkin_make everything once you have essentially git cloned it into source, however I swear half the time the libraries are not being created. I assume moveit_ros should compile the move_group node into the moveit_ros_move_group folder within catkin_ws/devel/lib as it did before, but now nothing.

Which brings me to my next question on how exactly do I go about applying the fix above?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-24**:
Did you check for missing system dependencies using rosdep? You also can use for installing catkinized and released ROS packages. In your workspace do `rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not really understand what is happening here. I am pretty sure things should run fine. What OS are you using? What version of boost is installed? Can you try to remove your devel/ and build/ folders, uninstall any moveit debs and recompile ? If the problem persists, can you e-mail me your urdf and config package? The format of the config packages has changed a bit, so maybe regenerating the package would help too.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-09-26**:
I'm not the one who meet this problem.But I'm curious about how to email to you? I can't find on your profile. Where can find someone's email? Thank you~